# Push_back() function does not work with vectors containing class objects

Tags: class, vector, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference

I have a little piece of code here with class Combat. The constructor of this class takes vector reference as a parameter and initializes private "MTeam" vector member. This class has a function combat() which accepts a vector of objects of class Monster by reference. I want this function to increase the number of elements in MTeam vector by 4. I wanted to Use push_back() function, but it doesn't work and gives me an error: **no instance of overloaded function matches the argument list argument types are: (int) object type is: std::vector>**

What is the problem here?

```
class Monster{
    int health;
    int protection;
public:
    void attack(){

    }
    void heal(){

    }

};

class Combat {
    vector<Monster>& MTeam;
public:

    Combat(vector<Monster>& MonsterTeam):MTeam(MonsterTeam) {

    }

    void IncreaseMembers() {
        MTeam.push_back(4);//here the programme gives an error
    }
};

int main()
{
    vector<Monster> MonsterTeam;

    Combat C;

    C.combat(MonsterTeam);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to push back integer 4 into your vector. push_back() accepts element of vector as a parameter.
Use `MTeam.resize(MTeam.size()+4);` instead

Comment: Thanks a lot. I haven't learned much about vectors yet, so sometimes I confuse some functions